# React Context not properly updated

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I use React Context to handle some global states within my app. The design is perhaps a bit poor at the moment, but somehow it does function, at least sometimes...

My problem is that some contexts are not updated properly when using `setX()`. It's a bit strange, but some of the contexts are updated correctly, and some are not, and others are updated but only when "using it twice". -> when pressing my button twice.

Here is some sample code - I get my contexts:

```
const { actualBatch, setActualBatch } = useContext(ActualBatch)
const { resultBatch, setResultBatch } = useContext(ResultBatch)
const { trainingStatus, setTrainingStatus } = useContext(TrainingStatus)
```

This is in my switchCase of the "handelButtonClick" funciton, I will later split up this:

Test case:

```
case "test":
                setActualBatch(unChunkingBatch(actualBatch))
                setActualBatch(actualBatch.pop())

                setIsLearningRunning(false);

                setTrainingStatus("Test")

                break;
```

Start case:

```
const handleButtonClick = (action) => {

        switch (action) {
            case "start":

                setIsLearningRunning(false)

                setTimeInSeconds(-3)

                setBatchSize(22)
                setChunkSize(5)

                setActualBatch(getRandomNumbersForTraining(batchSize,ChunkSize))


                setActualChunkIndex(0);

                setIsLearningRunning(true);

                setTrainingStatus("Train")

                break;
```

So the problem is, that for example "trainingStatus" (context) is set correctly, since my GUI renders with like it should:

```
 return (
        <div className="max-h-5/6 w-full h-5/6 bg-gradient-to-tr from-cyan-500 to-cyan-900 rounded-2xl m-4 text-center  flex items-center justify-center">

            {trainingStatus === "DefaultMessage" && <strong className={"text-white text-4xl"}>Press button to start.</strong>}

            {trainingStatus === "Train" && <MnemoTrain/>}
            {trainingStatus === "Pause" && <p className={"text-center text-white text-4xl"}>PAUSE...</p>}
            {trainingStatus === "Test" && <MnemoTest />}
            {trainingStatus === "Result" && <MnemoResult/>}

        </div>
    );
```

The components are shown correctly, so i think this state is set.

But i have Bugs with other states. For example i set the chunkSize and batchSize when pressing the start button. But in the GUI i need to press the button twice, and then the states are set. When pressing the button the first time, default values are used...

So my question is: It's a bit strange how those states behave. Is this due to asynchron "flow"? Or do i use the context in a false way?
your text
this is my unchunking method / wrapper:

```
export function unChunkingBatch(batch) {
    return batch.flat();
}
```

Thanks for your help. appreciate it

I tried several things an different states / values. I played with the Arrays saved in the states and tried different implementations.

Comment: using console.log to debug shows that my helper functions work properly. but updates of the states are not made correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use set state functions like that

```
 setIsLearningRunning(() => false);
 setTrainingStatus(() => "Test")
```

In react when updating multiple states from one function some strange behaviour happens which you can see from that link maybe it would be more better if you firstly see that link and understand how state work in such situations and next move on solution

- https://www.andreadiotallevi.com/blog/how-to-handle-multiple-set-state-calls-on-the-same-object-in-react
- https://typeofnan.dev/why-you-cant-setstate-multiple-times-in-a-row/

personally i recommend to use useReducer if you have such large amount of states to manage docs about useReducer

- https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer

Comment: thanks. the links are helpful.
i tried this:
setIsLearningRunning(() => false);
for all my states in one case. But seems not to function.

perhaps i should wrap my states in one object for one context, i thought i would do this anyway.

And whats about the reducer? Cann a pass a reducer to my context provider?

Comment: yes you can use useReducer with your context provider firstly you have to create dispatch and state with useReducer hook and determine how would they work next pass them to provider value and use where you want

Comment: if i would be on your place i would simplify and remove some states or i would try in the different application more simpler case and then come back and continue on harder case

Comment: since i've learned react "form scratch" with this project the design / arch is really poor. Since i thought "using global state management with contexts" would be a really nice idea .... -> i've tons of contexts now and the either not wrapped as objects but single states, sometimes array, what i later found out. So anyway i need to do some cleanup

Comment: the real question is: I have my Component for my application, being a part of my website under others. what i need is to do some state management and dependent render stuff in this app, since i have multiple states of the app und multiple contents and computations. what would then be the professional way to do this. as i read in the net, this would not be a context...

Comment: i spoke to a colleague of mine, and she recommended to replace the contexts with states on the highest level of the app. but this would be commonly the same "shit" since i needed to pass all the probs down to the subcomponents. etc. so the only difference would be that it's not a context but a state

Comment: i would recommend to use  useReducer hook to manage states correctly and remove lots of state declarations, on the other hand you can check redux tookit which is also great library for state managemen

Comment: thanks very much. i made a workaround for my prototype, cleanup states and wrapped in one object / state / context. now it's running. later on i will use reducer or redux at all. but for the simple prototype it's ok. thank you for your information and your help. kind regards

Comment: i am happy to hear that ^^